# 301 Redirect not working properly

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect one of my post with the following code but its not working I don't know what's wrong with the code. Can someone please tell me what mistake I have done?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /blog/
</IfModule>

Redirect 301 /blog/2012/11/27/url-here.html http://example.com/blog/php/url-here/
```

Comment: Is this WP installation?

Comment: So if you directly goto: `http://example.com/blog/php/url-here/` does it show correct WP page/post?

Comment: @anubhava yes it shows

Comment: ok I will post an answer, try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert this rule just below RewriteBase line in your WP .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^2012/11/27/url-here\.html$ php/url-here/ [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: many thanks, its working can you please describe it a little more?

Comment: Since you're using `RewriteBase /blog/` in your .htaccess URIs that you need to match will omit `blog/` from front and same thing about the target part also. Also ordering of these rules is important because these rewrites need to happen before regular WP rules take over that's why I asked to insert this just below RewriteBase line.

Comment: but if i had more then one url to redirect? is the same code working for more then one url redirect?

Comment: We can use regular expressions to catch multiple URIs/ Do they all start with `/blog/2012/11/27/` ?

Comment: :( this is the main problem actually, not with the same digits fields, i have to put all the fields manually, but yes the code working fine with the multiple url redirect :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^blog/2013/01/07/free-buttons-for-online-payment-gateway-service-provider.html$ /blog/php/free-buttons-for-online-payment-gateway-service-provider/ [R=301]
```

The second line check if the url begin with blog/2012/11/27/ and end with .html, and if it's the case, the page is redirected.

Comment: I edited my code. I know it's not the code that you want to use, but just say me if this code is working.

Comment: sorry but still the code is not working. Is there some other possibilities to not working this redirect?

Comment: And when you say the code is not working, you have a 404 error ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33788/discussion-between-jogesh-pi-and-lucas-willems)